# how to convert polyline to bitmap in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, polyline

I have a polyline, given as 2 vectors X, Y, of coordinates, both vectors of the same length, and X(i) corresponds to Y(i).

I need an easy way to create a boolean matrix, that has 1 where a polyline passes, and 0 where it doesn't.

is there a nice way of doing this?

I thought about poly2mask, but doc says it closes the polygon, which is not what i am looking for

Thanks

Comment: Are your `(X,Y)` coordinates uniformly distributed? Can you add a [mcve]

Comment: The coordinates are not uniformly distributed, but i have a function that can interpolate uniformly between them if needed. I do not see the correct way to do so, however, because i need to get information in pixels. Also see edit

Answer (score 0):

you can extend the line to the left and right edge of the graph. just copy the row numbers and change column to first and last. then add top-left and top-right corners into the coordinate array. use `poly2mask` to draw that huge polygon. then remove everything except the last line of the polygon. finally trim the left and right ends.

you can also use [`line`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) to draw lines.

Comment: I do not understand most of what you wrote. Would appreciate code to clarify

Comment: @Gulzar so any work you have done so far? example data and expected result?